# Linux alternative to MacOS Hazel with GUI for automated file management?

Tags: software-recommendation, filemanager

So far I've only found 3 Apps to replace [Hazel on Linux](https://alternativeto.net/software/hazel/?platform=linux) for automated file organization:

1. [Easy File Organizer](https://qiplex.com/software/easy-file-organizer/): 
   I tested the free download and read the manual but it doesn't look nearly as powerful as Hazel (maybe I'm wrong?)
2. [Maid](https://github.com/benjaminoakes/maid) and [Organize](https://github.com/tfeldmann/organize):

they're supposed to be powerful but I know nothing about scripts and command line, and I don't thing anybody made a GUI for them.

Thanks for the insight!