# User-Friendly Automated File Organization

Tags: wine, filemanager, automation

I once used DropIt on Windows 10. Unfortunately, it's not compatible with Ubuntu. I've tried Dolphin as an alternative, but it can't do what I need.

I need either a way to install DropIt to make it work on Ubuntu without a great amount of technical knowledge, or a substitute that can do what DropIt does.

For the former: something which only requires a few copy-and-paste commands into the command line, direct installs, or Applmage/Snap downloads would do.

For latter, I need the following functions and features:

- User-friendly interface with minimum code (e.g., Boolean logic filter parameters, not Linux queries)
- Set multi-factor parameters (e.g., <5 KB, text type, within Video Games folder, does not contain "Incomplete" or "Scraps" in title)
- Can see inside file contents for the sake of filtering files and sending files to a specified destination (e.g., "Within Video Games folder, send to "Pokemon" subfolder if file content contains "Charizard")
- Filter many files at a time (Easy File Organizer has a limit of 30)

I am running Cinnamon on the latest version of Ubuntu, re-configured to look like Windows Vista, and I have installed Wine. (DropIt isn't even mentioned on Wine's website, in case you're wondering.)

It seems someone asked a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182439/linux-alternative-to-macos-hazel-with-gui-for-automated-file-management) before, but it wasn't answered.

Comment: I have no answer, but have [this link](https://alternativeto.net/software/dropit/) which *may* get you something close to what you're after.

Comment: Of those, it seems only Easy File Organizer is even compatible with Linux/Ubuntu, and it won't work for folders with more than 30 files. (I have 271 files in one target folder alone, apparently.) I updated my question so it referenced Easy File Organizer, not Dolphin.